# What will happen if many people commit one crime?

Tags: criminal-law

For example, if 100 or 1000 participants plan and murder someone in such a manner that they are equally guilty for example, they mutually came with the idea and willingly participated and so on, you get the idea.

Will all be convicted of murder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the act and the evidence is sufficient, they will all be convicted. It would not be necessary, for example, to prove that it was Brutus's stab that killed the victim. It is not guaranteed that *all* of the participants committed the act knowed as [1st degree homicide](http://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=9A.32.030) (picking Washington law), some may be guilty of [conspiracy to murder](https://app.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=9A.28.040). [Liability for a crime](https://app.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=9A.08.020) can extend to others besides the person who "did it":

> (3) A person is an accomplice of another person in the commission of a
>   crime if: (a) With knowledge that it will promote or facilitate the
>   commission of the crime, he or she: (i) Solicits, commands,
>   encourages, or requests such other person to commit it; or (ii) Aids
>   or agrees to aid such other person in planning or committing it

Answer (score 1):

There was a cause in the UK where a group of 15 people beat up a man, who died from the assault. It was not clear whether anyone wanted him to die, and there is no evidence that anyone on his own would have killed him.

All fifteen were convicted for conspiracy to murder.

Comment: I think joint enterprise no longer applies in the UK, so the only person to be guilty of murder (or this sounds more like reckless manslaughter since nobody intended for the victim to die) is the person that delivered the fatal blow. The person that delivered the fatal blow is not necessarily the last person to touch the victim, but the person who injured the victim enough to cause them to eventually die from their injuries (look into the Common Law but-for test).